# Define $T:L^2[0,1]\to L^2[0,1]$ by $Tf(t)=\int_0^1 \frac{f(s)ds}{1+s^2+t^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

We want to show that $T$ is self-adjoint and compact.

To show that $T$ is self-adjoint we show

$$\begin{align} 
\langle Tf(t),g(t)\rangle
 &= \int_0^1 Tf(t)\cdot g(t)dt \\
 & = \int_0^1 \left(g(t)\left( \int_0^1 \frac{f(s)ds}{1+s^2+t^2} \right)dt\right) \\
 &=^? \int_0^1 \left( f(t) \left(\int_0^1 \frac{g(s)ds}{1+s^2+t^2} \right) dt\right) \\
 &=\langle f(t),Tg(t)\rangle 
\end{align}$$ Would you do this with a substitution? Maybe Fubini's theorem? I'm not really sure where to go with this.

For compactness, consider a bounded sequence $\{f_n\}$, say by $M$, in $L^2[0,1]$. We need to show that $$Tf_n=\int_0^1 \frac{f_n(s)ds}{1+s^2+t^2}\leq M\int_0^1\frac{ds}{1+s^2+t^2}$$ has a convergent subsequence. This one I'm not sure how to approach at all.

Any help for either problem would be much appreciated, thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Self-adjointness: the inner product doesn't have to be with a $t.$ First note that we can write
$$(Tg)(s)=\int_0^1\frac{g(t)\,dt}{1+s^2+t^2}.$$

Then you can recognize the following:
\begin{align*}
\langle Tf, g\rangle&=\int_0^1 (Tf)(t)\,g(t)\,dt \\
&=\int_0^1\left[\int_0^1\frac{f(s)\,ds}{1+s^2+t^2}\right]g(t)\,dt \\
&=\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{f(s)\,g(t)}{1+s^2+t^2}\,ds\,dt \\
&=\int_0^1 f(s)\left[\int_0^1\frac{g(t)}{1+s^2+t^2}\,dt\right]ds \\
&=\int_0^1f(s)\,(Tg)(s)\,ds \\
&=\langle f, Tg\rangle.
\end{align*}
I've switched the order of integration, which should be no problem in $L^2$ on a rectangular region of integration. As you mentioned, might need to invoke Fubini.

As for compactness, let $k(s,t)=\dfrac{1}{1+s^2+t^2}$ be the kernel of the integral operator $T.$ Note that 
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 k(s,t)\,ds\,dt<\infty, $$
hence the integral operator is [Hilbert-Schmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_integral_operator), and hence $T$ is compact.

Comment: Not using the $t$ also makes this more convenient. It seems a little too simple but Fubini's theorem is also quite simple. Do you have any idea for the compactness?

Comment: I just looked it up, and found that your $T$ is Hilbert-Schmidt, and hence compact. I've added that to the answer.

Comment: Would there be a different way to do it? We didn't use kernels and Hilbert-Schmidt operators at all.

Comment: From the wiki page on compact operators (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator#Origins_in_integral_equation_theory), it appears you can also use Arzela-Ascoli. That's probably in some textbook or other. I don't have any reference books with me right now, unfortunately.

Comment: Neat! Thanks for your help :)